# insert error column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.storMember 
( 
    @Check nchar (1), 
    @UserName nvarchar (15), 
    @Passowerd nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @Name nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @Phone nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @email nvarchar (30)=null, 
    @CompanyName nvarchar (15)=null , 
    @Gender nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @BarthDay datetime =null, 
    @Question nvarchar (15)=null, 
    @answer nvarchar (100)=null ) 
AS 

if @check = 'a' 
    begin 
        insert into Member values
       (@Check,@UserName,@Passowerd,@Name,@Phone,@email,@CompanyName,@Gender,@BarthDay,@Question,@answer) 
    end

if @Check = 'u'
    begin
        UPDATE Member 
        SET Passowerd = @Passowerd, 
        [Name] = @Name, 
        Phone = @Phone,
        email =@email, 
        CompanyName = @CompanyName, 
        Gender = @Gender, 
        BarthDay = @BarthDay, 
        Question = @Question, 
        Answer = @Answer 
        WHERE (UserName=@UserName) 
    end 

if @check= 'd'
    begin 
        Delete from member 
        where (userName = @userName) 
    end 
return
```

Comment: Error message isn't clear?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the column name if you want to insert the values in specific columns.

```
insert into Member (CheckColumnName,Usernamecolumnname,NamecolumnName,PhoneColumnName,EmailColumnName,CompanyNameColumnNmae,GenderColumnNmae,BarthdayColumnNmae,QuestionColumnName,AnswerColumnName) values
   (@Check,@UserName,@Passowerd,@Name,@Phone,@email,@CompanyName,@Gender,@BarthDay,@Question,@answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

here in the sql server ...

if you want to insert properly ..

1> go to database

2> right click on table

3> option : "script table as "

4> then "insert into "

you will get whole insert Query of your table 
and  then pass your all params according to columns .